# ASP.NET turn off FriendlyURLs mobile.master page

Tags: asp.net, friendly-url

I would like to turn the Site.Mobile.Master page off completely. My site is responsive and i want mobile browsers to use the same master page.

How can i do this in ASP.NET friendly URLs

Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Delete the Site.Mobile.Master page, and Friendly URLs will just use the regular Site.Master page instead.

Comment: This answer does not work in all situations as of March 2021. See the answer by MikeBaz for a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 15):

There actually seems to be a bug in the current version of Web Forms friendly URLs (1.0.2) that makes this attempted access to the `site.mobile.master` break with `"The relative virtual path 'Site.Mobile.Master' is not allowed here."` in the friendly URL code.  I just was burned by this.

To fix it, I used a modified version of the code at http://www.davidwilhelmsson.com/disabling-mobile-master-pages-with-asp-net-friendly-urls/ - first made a resolver class:

```
/// <summary>
/// This is a hack to force no mobile URL resolution in FriendlyUrls.  There's some kind of bug in the current version that
/// causes it to do an internal failed resolve of a mobile master even though there is none.
/// </summary>
public class BugFixFriendlyUrlResolver: Microsoft.AspNet.FriendlyUrls.Resolvers.WebFormsFriendlyUrlResolver {
    protected override bool TrySetMobileMasterPage(HttpContextBase httpContext, Page page, string mobileSuffix) {
        return false;
        //return base.TrySetMobileMasterPage(httpContext, page, mobileSuffix);
    }
}
```

then used it in my `RouteConfig` class:

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes) {
        var settings = new FriendlyUrlSettings();
        settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Permanent;
        routes.EnableFriendlyUrls(settings, new BugFixFriendlyUrlResolver());
    }
```

Comment: not sure I understand the question.  The resolver class is just a class in the project, registered in the standard out of the box `RouteConfig` in `App_Start` as shown.  `RouteConfig` is called from `Global.asax.cs`.

Comment: i ended up putting it in the App_Start

Comment: That's the only solution where I can really delete Site.Mobile.Master. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

It is relly weird that there is no easy way to get rid of mobile master page. If I delete Site.Mobile.Master.master, I ended with the error "The file '/Site.Mobile.Master' does not exists".

What I did to solve this issue was I added following codes into Site.Mobile.Master.cs Page_Load event.

```
var AlternateView = "Desktop";
var switchViewRouteName = "AspNet.FriendlyUrls.SwitchView";
var url = GetRouteUrl(switchViewRouteName, new { view = AlternateView, __FriendlyUrls_SwitchViews = true });
url += "?ReturnUrl=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Request.RawUrl);
Response.Redirect(url);
```

Answer (score 2):

When I deleted Site.Mobil.Master the pages was broken.
So...
I prefer just set in Site.Mobile.Master set the info of Site.Master

CodeBehind="Site.Master.cs" Inherits="App.SiteMaster"

its not the best option(LOL), but Solved!

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for me. Ridiculous. Replaced everything in the Site.Mobile.Master with my Site.Master file, except for Line 1 (<%@ Master..... %>) which I updated as suggested above.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to solve this problem, by changing following:

1) I deleted mobile.master

2) I changed code at ViewSwitcher.ascx.cs to folowing

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CurrentView = "Desktop";
        AlternateView = "Desktop";

        // Create switch URL from the route, e.g. ~/__FriendlyUrls_SwitchView/Mobile?ReturnUrl=/Page
        var switchViewRouteName = "AspNet.FriendlyUrls.SwitchView";
        var switchViewRoute = RouteTable.Routes[switchViewRouteName];
        if (switchViewRoute == null)
        {
            // Friendly URLs is not enabled or the name of the switch view route is out of sync
            this.Visible = false;
            return;
        }
        var url = GetRouteUrl(switchViewRouteName, new { view = AlternateView, __FriendlyUrls_SwitchViews = true });
        url += "?ReturnUrl=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Request.RawUrl);
        SwitchUrl = url;

    }
```

3) This didn't work, until I deleted whole directory and republished it. I think, deleting some specific files might help as well. But since I didn't have that kind of environment, then I went easier way.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an article I have written to fix this issue. Please refer.

http://www.icodefor.net/2015/06/fixes-for-the-issue-the-relative-virtual-path-site.mobile.master-is-not-allowed-here-in-asp.net-friendly-urls.html

Comment: I can't find TrySetMobileMasterPage() anywhere in the default VS web  project. Is there a different method for this in VS2013?

Comment: I found it buried in the Microsoft.AspNet.FriendlyUrls.dll
I suppose MS won't provide that source code (not that you actually need it)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it simply adding at the end of "Page_Load" event of "ViewSwitcher.ascx" the redirection saved by default:
    Response.Redirect(url)
So the sub results in:

> Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
>           ' Determinar la vista actual
>           Dim isMobile = WebFormsFriendlyUrlResolver.IsMobileView(New HttpContextWrapper(Context))
>           CurrentView = If(isMobile, "Mobile", "Desktop")
>
> ```
>     ' Determinar la vista alternativa
>     AlternateView = If(isMobile, "Desktop", "Mobile")
>
>     ' Create URL de conmutador a partir de la ruta, p. ej. ~/__FriendlyUrls_SwitchView/Mobile?ReturnUrl=/Page
>     Dim switchViewRouteName = "AspNet.FriendlyUrls.SwitchView"
>     Dim switchViewRoute = RouteTable.Routes(switchViewRouteName)
>     If switchViewRoute Is Nothing Then
>         ' Las URL descriptivas no están habilitadas o el nombre de la ruta de la vista del conmutador no está sincronizado
>         Me.Visible = False
>         Return
>     End If
>     Dim url = GetRouteUrl(switchViewRouteName, New With {
>         .view = AlternateView,
>         .__FriendlyUrls_SwitchViews = True
>     })
>     url += "?ReturnUrl=" & HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Request.RawUrl)
>     SwitchUrl = url
>     **Response.Redirect(url)**
> End Sub
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I found it easier to just delete (or rename) Site.Mobile.Master and ViewSwitcher.ascx. This seemed to work just fine for me.